# Android WebView zoom controls only with image not html

Tags: android, webview

I am working on an android app with a webview element and local html pages and images.

When a link goes to and image (example: images/image.png) I want to let the user zoom in and out.

But I don't want the zoom to work on the html pages.

This is why `webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);` doesn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simple actually.

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            String fileEx = url.substring(Math.max(0, url.length() - 3));

            if(fileEx.equals("jpg")){
                webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            }else{
                webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            }

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: please substitute " view.loadUrl(url); return true;" (which can lead to bugs) with "return false;".

Answer (score 1):

You could specify `user-scalable=no` on your viewport to disable user scaling. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) for more on the viewport tag.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to call `webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);` when the link goes to the image and `webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);` when the users back to main html

Comment: Well I can't change the setting if the image was linked from a html file.

Comment: You are showing some local images, Where a user clicks a image (or button) to see the image, Right?

Comment: The exact thing I  wanted to say... good it worked for you :D